# Oracle: TIMESTAMP data type

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, timestamp

i am using timestamp for a field to store date and time, however when i fetch the rows from the table i get loads of zeros in the timestamp field.

```
SQL> select * from booking_session;

     BK_ID|BK_DATE
----------|-------------------------
         1|18-MAR-12 10.00.00.000000
         2|18-MAR-12 10.25.00.000000
         3|18-MAR-12 10.30.00.000000
         4|18-MAR-12 10.35.00.000000
         5|18-MAR-12 10.40.00.000000
```

The following is the insert statement

> INSERT INTO BOOKING_SESSION VALUES (1,TO_TIMESTAMP('18/03/2012 10:00',
>   'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI')

Can someone please tell me how can the bk_date format be stored like `18-MAR-12 10.00` or at least have AM or PM next to it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare `BK_DATE` column as `timestamp(precision)` where precision is a number of decimal digits to store fraction of a second. So you might have declared `BK_DATE timestamp(0)`. If you do not need track time down to a fraction of a second use `date` data type to store dates. In any case time part (hh:mi:ss) will be there and if you insert data as you did, specifying only hour and minutes, then seconds will be fill in with zeros. You can use `to_char` function and appropriate date format mask to get rid of those trailing zeros at display time:

```
-- sample of data
SQL> with t1(BK_ID, BK_DATE) as(
  2    select 1, to_timestamp('18-MAR-12 10.00.00.000000', 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SSxFF6') from dual union all
  3    select 2, to_timestamp('18-MAR-12 10.25.00.000000', 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SSxFF6') from dual union all
  4    select 3, to_timestamp('18-MAR-12 10.30.00.000000', 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SSxFF6') from dual union all
  5    select 4, to_timestamp('18-MAR-12 10.35.00.000000', 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SSxFF6') from dual union all
  6    select 5, to_timestamp('18-MAR-12 10.40.00.000000', 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SSxFF6') from dual
  7  )
  8  select bk_id
  9       , to_char(bk_date, 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI') bk_date
 10    from t1
 11  ;


     BK_ID BK_DATE
---------- ------------------------
         1 18-MAR-12 10:00
         2 18-MAR-12 10:25
         3 18-MAR-12 10:30
         4 18-MAR-12 10:35
         5 18-MAR-12 10:40
```

Comment: Thanks alot, i am trying to construct a query to fetch all records matching the date only but i am having issues. something like `select * from booking_session where bk_date = to_date('18-03-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy');` it isnt working for me, thanks alot

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos that kind of comparison will always evaluates to false because `bk_date` has a time part. And when you use `to_date()` and do not specify time part, the midnight will be assign by default. So `18-MAR-2012 10:00:00 <> 18-MAR-2012 00:00:00`. To make that happen you might write: to_char(bk_date, 'DD-MON-YY', 'NLS_LANGUAGE=english') = '12-NOV-2012'

Comment: I tried the following but get an error `select * from booking_session where bk_date = to_char(bk_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY', 'NLS_LANGUAGE=english') ='18-03-2012';` command not ended properly

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos `select * from booking_session where TRUNC(bk_date) = TO_DATE('18-03-2012', 'DD.MM.YYYY')` OR `select * from booking_session where to_char(bk_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') ='18-03-2012'`

Comment: Q. WHY are you using a timestamp for this?  A normal oracle date column holds the date and the time quite nicely.  Never pull the L-Value  in a query statement though a function if the column is indexed, it will push you into a instantaneous table scan.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```
select * from booking_session where trunc(bk_date) = to_date('18-03-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy');
```

Comment: this will kill performance instantly if the column is indexed.